# Find GS: $(D-1)^{3}(D-2)^{1}(D^{2}-6D+10)y(x)=0$ where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find GS: $(D-1)^{3}(D-2)^{1}(D^{2}-6D+10)y(x)=0$ where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$

Is this one even solvable? Should I multiply everything out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(D-1)^{3}(D-2)^{1}(D^{2}-6D+10)y(x)=0$$

1) $(D-1)^3$

$$D=1 \text { multiplicity 3 } \implies y_1(x)=c_1e^x+c_2xe^x+c_3x^2e^x$$

2)$(D-2)$

$$D=2 \implies y_2(x)=c_4e^{2x}$$

3)$ D^{2}-6D+10$
$$\Delta=-4 \implies D={3\pm 2i} \implies y_3(x)=c_5e^{3x}\cos(2x)+c_6e^{3x}\sin(2x)$$
Therefore the general solution of the equation is :

$$y(x)=y_1+y_2+y_3$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2xe^x+c_3x^2e^x+c_4e^{2x}+c_5e^{3x}\cos(2x)+c_6e^{3x}\sin(2x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note the roots of the quadratic term are
$$
\frac{6 \pm \sqrt{6^2-4\cdot 1 \cdot 10}}{2\cdot 1}
 = \frac{6 \pm \sqrt{-4}}{2} = 3 \pm 2i,
$$
where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

So the general solution for the first term has root of $1$ with multiplicity $3$, hence contributes $$e^x + xe^x + x^2e^x.$$

Can you finish the rest?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still not sure how to proceed. What exactly will knowing the solution to the quadratic portion do for me?